# Performance difference in Pandas querying a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

Lets say I have a data frame

```
purchase_1 = pd.Series({'Name': 'Chris',
                        'Item Purchased': 'Dog Food',
                        'Cost': 22.50})
purchase_2 = pd.Series({'Name': 'Kevyn',
                        'Item Purchased': 'Kitty Litter',
                        'Cost': 2.50})
purchase_3 = pd.Series({'Name': 'Vinod',
                        'Item Purchased': 'Bird Seed',
                        'Cost': 5.00})

df = pd.DataFrame([purchase_1, purchase_2, purchase_3], index=['Store 1', 'Store 1', 'Store 2'])
```

My question is that is there any performance issue/difference between these 2 code blocks

```
#code number 1
%time
print(df[df['Cost'] > 3]['Name'])
OUT[3]:CPU times: user 6 µs, sys: 2 µs, total: 8 µs
      Wall time: 14.8 µs

#Code number 2
%time
print(df['Name'][df['Cost'] > 3])
OUT[4]:CPU times: user 4 µs, sys: 0 ns, total: 4 µs
       Wall time: 7.39 µs
```

Comment: I'd also test it against print(df.loc[df['Cost'] > 3, 'Name']).

Comment: That's the fastest way @EricTruett. You should never have `][` when using pandas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In code number 1 you are first slicing, which will return a data frame and then you get the series. In the second code, you are getting the series and slicing it, since the series is always smaller than the data frame, the second code is faster. This is almost imperceptible in a small case like that but if you had a huge dataset with lots of columns, the second code would be a lot faster.

I would recommend using `.loc` as @EricTruett said, here is a comparison between the 3:

```
%%timeit -n 1000
df[df['Cost'] > 3]['Name']
397 µs ± 18.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%%timeit -n 1000
df['Name'][df['Cost'] > 3]
306 µs ± 54.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%%timeit -n 1000
df.loc[df['Cost'] > 3, 'Name']
235 µs ± 19.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness I've added `%timeit (df.query('Cost > 3').Name)`

```
%timeit (df[df['Cost'] > 3]['Name'])

%timeit (df['Name'][df['Cost'] > 3])

%timeit (df.query('Cost > 3').Name)

%timeit (df.loc[df['Cost'] > 3, 'Name'])
```

resulting in

```
417 µs ± 11.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
267 µs ± 8.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
1.21 ms ± 22.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
224 µs ± 4.88 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```